# Passing Argument to Comment in .sh script

Tags: slurm, block-comment

I am a beginner in the use of .sh scripts so please excuse my ignorance. This is my problem:

To submit my jobs to our cluster the corresponding submit file has to contain a "slurm header" and looks something like this.

```
#!/bin/sh 
#
########## Begin Slurm header ##########
#
#SBATCH --job-name=blabla
#
########### End Slurm header ##########

# Load module
module load math/matlab/R2020a

# Start a Matlab program
matlab -nodesktop -r "program $1 $2"

exit
```

Notice that I am passing two arguments to this .sh file which are then passed on to the matlab program. How can I make the job-name in the Slurm header dynamic according to the input arguments?

Simply writing `#SBATCH --job-name=blabla$1$2` predictably doesn't work.

Comment: is there some reason to require the job name to be set within the in-file header, and not to e.g. just submit the jobs with something like `sbatch --job-name "foo bar" script.sh foo bar`?

Comment: @ilkkachu I thought about that a while ago as well. Since my wrapper.sh does a loop like `for ii, jj ... do sbatch script.sh $ii $jj` I would have to pass the two arguments to script.sh anyways and just making the jobname in the slurm header dynamic seems to keep the wrapper.sh and the script.sh much better human readable (I am very unlikely to do much .sh scripting in the future so coming back later and knowing what I did is a huge plus for me). 
Or is there a way to load a bunch of slurm options and run *both* matlab lines in a one liner inside a loop like you suggest, but well readable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SLURM: Custom standard output name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285690/slurm-custom-standard-output-name)

Comment: You don't have to provide the job name in #SBATCH comments (which are shell **comments** that are interpreted by the sbatch command, not by bash - you can't use bash variables in them).  You can use sbatch's `-J` or `--job-name` option  (e.g. `sbatch -J "blabla$1$2" ...`).   The `#SBATCH` comments are just a convenience feature, a way of embedding sbatch command-line options into the job script.

Comment: @cas Thanks for the suggested post. However I do need the input variable $1$2 in the job name, not just any dynamic job name.

Comment: re-read my comment and the linked Q&A, and ilkkachu's comments too I don't think you understood them. The point is you can pass the job name to sbatch on the command line, not just in #SBATCH comments.  The example I gave was probably a bit confusing, in the for loop in your script that you mention, you'd use `sbatch -J "blabla$ii$jj" script.sh`.   Inside the sbatch job script itself, the job name can be accessed via the `$SLURM_JOB_NAME` variable - it's set by `sbatch` when it runs.  There are also numerous other `$SLURM_*` env vars available (including `$SLURM_JOB_ID`). See `man sbatch`

Comment: Using the `-J` / `--job-name` command line option or setting and exporting the `SBATCH_JOBNAME` environment variable are the ONLY ways you can pass a dynamic job name to an `sbatch` script.  You can NOT use #SBATCH comments **because** they're just comments: the shell does not expand variables or positional parameters like $1 or $2 in comments.

Comment: The *scope* of positional parameters ($1, $2, $3, etc) is limited to the shell script that received them on the command line.  They are NOT passed on automatically to child processes like `sbatch` (or any other program - e.g. running grep in a script doesn't automatically pass the script's `$1` to grep) - you have to do that manually if/when you need it.  Child processes have their own set of arguments given when the child process is executed in the shell script.      The -J option and/or the SBATCH_JOB_NAME variable are the two ways you can pass the scripts arguments on to sbatch.

Comment: BTW, terdon's answer is good but it's not necessary.  If you can write a script that generates a batch script with a dynamic `#SBATCH --job-name="$1$2"` comment, the same script can just run sbatch directly with the --job-name option.  The end result is exactly the same, but without needing an intermediary job file: the job is run with the job-name you want it to have.

Comment: @cas thanks a lot. yes I do understand your point. I do still need to have a script that includes both matlab lines though and to which I need to pass both input variables anyways, right?

Comment: I've written an example as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can. All lines starting with `#` are ignored by the shell, and the `$1` and `$2` are shell things. Many job managers, including slurm, have some commands that are written as shell comments, so ignored by the shell, but are read by the job manager. This is what your `SBATCH` line is:

```
#SBATCH --job-name=blabla
```

So there is no way of doing this dynamically within the same script. However, you can make a wrapper script that does this. For example:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
cat <<EoF
#!/bin/sh 
#
########## Begin Slurm header ##########
#
#SBATCH --job-name=blabla$1$2
#
########### End Slurm header ##########

# Load module
module load math/matlab/R2020a

# Start a Matlab program
matlab -nodesktop -r "program $1 $2"

exit
EoF
```

If you now run this script with two parameters, it will print out the script you actually want:

```bsh
$ foo.sh param1 param2
#!/bin/sh 
#
########## Begin Slurm header ##########
#
#SBATCH --job-name=blablaparam1param2
#
########### End Slurm header ##########

# Load module
module load math/matlab/R2020a

# Start a Matlab program
matlab -nodesktop -r "program param1 param2"

exit
```

So you can just do:

```
foo.sh param1 param2 > slurm_script.sh
```

Comment: Just out of fun, I tried `$(echo "#SBATCH --job-name=$1$2")` - but `bash` then actually tries to execute a command `#SBATCH` instead of treating the result as comment. Somewhat expected but still -no luck there ;)

Comment: @ilkkachu no, not at all. Slurm will only be given the `slurm_script.sh` script. At the moment, the OP is writing that manually, but this would allow them to do it automatically and change the slurm header as desired.

Comment: @ilkkachu no, I mean that the original process was "manually write a slurm script that takes two arguments" and the problem is that that would not allow the slurm header to be set automatically since that is a comment to the shell. My solution is "automate the writing of the slurm script so that you can set the comment as well". The difference is that the OP will run scriptA to generate scriptB instead of writing scriptB manually.

Answer (score 5):

Write an sbatch job script like the following, with just the commands you want run in the job:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh 

# you can include #SBATCH comments here if you like, but any that are
# specified on the command line or in SBATCH_* environment variables
# will override whatever is defined in the comments.  You **can't**
# use positional parameters like $1 or $2 in a comment - they won't
# do anything.

# Load module
module load math/matlab/R2020a

# Start a Matlab program
# give it five arguments, -nodesktop, -r, program, and two
# more that you pass in as arguments to THIS script.
matlab -nodesktop -r "program" "$1" "$2"

# alternatively (since I don't know how matlab runs "program",
# or how it handles args or how it passes them on to a matlab
# script), maybe just three args:
# matlab -nodesktop -r "program $1 $2"

exit
```

save it as whatever you like - e.g. `./mymatlabjob.sh` - and make it executable with `chmod +x mymatlabjob.sh`

Then run it like so on the command line:

```
sbatch --job-name "whatever job name you want" ./mymatlabjob.sh arg1 arg2
```

where `arg1` and `arg2` are the arguments you want to pass on to the matlab job.

Or in a nested loop like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

for i in 1 2 3; do
  for j in 3 2 1; do
    sbatch --job-name "blablah$i$j" ./mymatlabjob.sh "$i" "$j"
  done
done
```

Running that will run 9 different jobs with sbatch, each with different job names - one for each iteration of $i and $j.

Comment: Perfect! This is even better, thanks. Is the "make it executable"-step absolutely needed? If yes, what does it do?

Comment: reload the page to see the edit, i forgot to pass on the arguments in the first version.

Comment: I'm not sure if making it executable is required or not.  I can't remember how sbatch and slurm handle job scripts that aren't executable (it may run them anyway, or maybe not).  It certainly doesn't hurt to make it executable.    `chmod +x` sets the `x` execute bit(s) in the file's permissions - this means you can just run it directly without having to run the interpreter (sh or bash) with the script as the first argument. `./myscript.sh` (or just `myscript.sh` if it's in a directory listed in $PATH) rather than `bash myscript.sh`.   The `#!` line tells linux which interpreter to use.

Comment: Thanks again very much. Your help is much appreciated and this is definitely the best way to do it for me. Since the question title and terdons answer match so well however I will leave the accept with terdon so that if people search for the "comment editing sh. scirpt" they find a matching answer.

Comment: That's fine - he was first to answer with something that works well enough for you.  I just wanted to make sure that you understood how sbatch and job names and sh or bash (and command-line options in general) work - because it's much easier to use tools if you understand the basics.

Comment: As far as I tested, it doesn't seem to need to need exec permission. Makes sense in a way: since it peeks inside the file for the the `#SBATCH` lines, it might as well interpret the `#!` line itself too.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't surprise me.  It's been years since I worked a lot with slurm, but I should have remembered that HPC users tend to forget (or not know) things like that because they're mostly researchers and academics, not sysadmins.  "did you remember to run chmod +x?" would be even more common than "have you tried turning it off and on again?" if it was required.

Comment: @stollenm accepting an answer is 100% a personal choice. If this is the answer you ended up using, then accept it. Don't worry, I will certainly not take it the wrong way.